# All sheaves in a Grothendieck topos are generated by subobjects of powers of a suitable sheaf

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, groupoids

Consider a topos $\mathcal E$. Butz and Moerdijk, in *Representing topoi by topological groupoids*, par. 2, say that one can find an object $S\in \mathcal E$ such that the subobjects of its powers (i.e., sheaves $B\subset S^n$ for some $n$) generate $\mathcal E$. They suggest to use $S=\sum_{c\in C}c$, where $C$ is a site of definition of $\mathcal E$. (I suppose they identify $c$ with $Yon(c)$.)

I have difficulties in finding out why this works. Perhaps my problem is that I don't understand in what sense the word "generate" is used.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Generate" means "everyone is a colimit of them", right ?

Comment: I don't have the article at hand, but usually in topos theory, a family of objects $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is generating when parallel morphisms $f,g : Y \to Z$ are equal as soon as $f\circ k = g\circ k$ for all $k:X_i\to Y$ and all $i\in I$ ; otherwise put, when the $\mathcal E(X_i,-)$ are jointly faithful.

Comment: If two maps in the topos of sheaves on $C$ are different, then they differ over some object $c$ at some value of the domain, that is, after composing with a map from the representable associated to $c$-or more precisely, the sheafification of that representable, in case the topology on $C$ fails to make the representables sheaves. Thus the given maps must differ on some subobject of the coproduct of all the representables, namely, on one of the representables.

Comment: But this must not be the intended sense of generation, since we didn't use any powers. Generation under colimits is also not the point here.  Do the authors really not explain what they mean by generation? I would also probably assume that the power $n$ is supposed to be an arbitrary small cardinal.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin Carlson's and Pece's answers are correct in explaining when a family of objects is generating. In every Grothendieck topos the collection of representable sheaves (i.e., the sheafifications of the Yoneda embedding are generating (this follows from sheafification applied to the contents of the Yoneda lemma). In general, if a site is at hand then the collection of subobjects of the co-product over all objects of that site has the property that its subobjects generate the topos. However, most often, much smaller objects are sufficient. If, for example, the topos is generated by a syntatic site, then the co-product over all finite products of finite types suffces.